# bookdown is taking pdflatex even though I explicitly stated xelatex

Tags: r, latex, pandoc, bookdown

I'm trying to create a book with `bookdown` as pdf. It works well creating an EPUB file.

My YAML is this:

```
--- 
title: "Title Here"
subtitle: "Subtitle here"
author: "me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
description: "description goes here."
cover-image: "cover.png"
lang: "es"
always_allow_html: true
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
  pdf_document2: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
---
```

At some point in chapter 4 I have a Japanese letter, U+305B.

I've tried creating the pdf book with:

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", output_format = bookdown::pdf_document2())
```

and

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", output_format = bookdown::pdf_book())
```

Both of them complain that:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character せ (U+305B)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

and recommend me to check [this part of the rmarkdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-unicode.html). From there is where I took the 4 last lines of the YAML preamble.

I couldn't help but noticing that the call to pandoc is taking `pdflatex` as the `pdf-engine` (see third-to-last line):

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS myFileName.knit.md --to latex 
  --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash 
  --output herramientasBasicasMejoramiento.tex 
  --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/bookdown/rmarkdown/lua/custom-environment.lua 
  --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua 
  --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua 
  --metadata-file /tmp/RtmpAbwGga/file565f3d087e3c --self-contained 
  --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --number-sections 
  --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics 
  --wrap preserve --variable tables=yes 
  --standalone -Mhas-frontmatter=false --citeproc
```

I'm working in Ubuntu and have installed both texlive and tinytex.

```
whereis xelatex
xelatex: /home/gp/bin/xelatex /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex
```

There is an [unanswered question with a problem that looks similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63689851/package-inputenc-error-unicode-character-u2003).

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the output format in a way that will see your `latex_engine` argument, e.g.

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document2")
```

(naming one of the output formats from your YAML), or

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", 
                      output_format = bookdown::pdf_document2(latex_engine = "xelatex"))
```

(specifying it independently).